# Python: Adding element to list at index with the same value

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list containing a number of ints and adding them to a second list at the index matching their value. The second list has already bin filled with placeholders ("X").
i.e:

```
firstlist = [2, 3, 5]
```

with the output:

```
secondlist = ['X', 'X', 2, 3, 'X', 5, 'X', 'X']
```

What is the best way to do so?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is second list contain before the output? In your example before the change does secondlist contain 8 X's or only 5 X's?

Comment: what did you try and what is the specific problem you have?

Comment: @GeeTransit the secondlist before being changed to the current output is just a list filled with 10 "X"s as placeholders.

Comment: @user7755 does that mean that the correct solution here would overwrite three Xs and delete one? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take a list argument and put them into a new list to be returned by the function.

```
def list_fill(first_list, fill, length=None):
    return [(i if i in first_list else fill) for i in (range(max(first_list) + 1) if length is None else range(length))]
```

How `list_fill` works:

The `first_list` argument includes the indexes to be changed.
The `fill` argument is what the empty spaces should be.
The third optional `length` argument specifies the length of the output. If left blank, it will take the max index specified in `first_list`.

Comment: This creates a new list, which seems to be at odds with what the OP is looking for. In fact it doesn't use the second list at all *shrug*

Comment: I've edited it so it can have a length argument. If the output list was desired to be length 5, you can use `list_fill((1, 3, 4), 'X', 5)`. The `secondlist` the OP had is just filled with `'X'`. You can put that in the `fill` argument.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree that this might be a superior method, but it does not appear to do what OP is wanting to do. It's possible that's just a matter of unclear specification though (*that's* never been a problem in programming :D)

Comment: I think the OP's `secondlist` serves no real purpose, just an output list created beforehand. Anyhow, functions can be used anywhere, so incase the OP is using this everywhere in their code, it can minimize code length :D

Comment: Never actually thought about filling a list with an if-else statement, but that actually does seem like an excellent way to add placeholders!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something as simple as this:

```
firstlist = [2, 3, 5]
secondlist = ['X']*10

for index in firstlist:
    secondlist[index] = index

print(secondlist)
# ['X', 'X', 2, 3, 'X', 5, 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Could have a `dict` for `firstlist` with indices for `key` and the value you want to place as `values` for the `dict`.

Comment: Actually yes! Never thought it was that simply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use .insert() if you want to keep the stuff that's already in secondlist.

```
firstlist = [2, 3, 5]
secondlist = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']

for x in range(len(firstlist)):
    secondlist.insert(firstlist[x], firstlist[x])

print(secondlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you  need to make a function `YourFunc(inputlist,length)` where `inputlist` argument is the list for input and `length` is the argument for the length of the list for output.
So, according to your question, `inputlist=[2,3,5]` and `length=8`.

```
def YourFunc(inputlist,length):
        out=[]
        for X in range (0,length):
                if inputlist.count(X)==1:
                         out.append(X)
                elif inputlist.count(X)==0:
                         out.append('X')
        print(out)

YourFunc([2,3,5],8)
```

So, this is how I usually do.
In this function a loop is running from `0`to `length`. If the is element is not in `inputlist` then `'X'` is inserted in output list `out`. If not, then the number in the loop is inserted.